# Evaluating Dynamic Variables in ArcGIS JavaScript Popup Templates and Feature Layers

Tags: javascript, dynamic, popup, arcgis, layer

I'm using ArcGIS JavaScript to create popup templates on my map. It's going great. However, I'm struggling to evaluate variables that I set outside the popupTemplate or FeatureLayer calls. For example, this works quite well. Everything is static.

```
  const layerOne = new FeatureLayer({
    id: "feature_layer_id",  
    url: "https://services3.arcgis.com/myFeatureServer/0", 
    popupTemplate: { 
      title: `A Title Goes Here`,
      content: `<table>
          <tr>
            <td><img class="esri-popup__custom-image imageTrim" width="75" src="{expression/logo_url}" /></td>
          </tr>             
        </table>`, 
      expressionInfos: [
        {
          name: "logo_url",
          title: "Logo URL",
          expression: `return "http://some.fully.qualified.url/path/image.png";`
          }
        ],
      }, 
    renderer: someRendererObj, 
    visible: false  
    });
```

The problem happens when I try to make it dynamic. For example, how about making the logo URL dynamic, such as:

```
expression: `return "http://some.fully.qualified.url/path/image-" + randomJSVariable + ".png";`
```

Variable `randomJSVariable` is set elsewhere in my JS, and could be referenced as `window.randomJSVariable`.

In this case the expression is not evaluated, and the img renders as broken. Can someone make a suggestion as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JS variables, pass a function to the `content` property instead of using `expressionInfos`:

```
content: (evt) => {
    // the variable "evt" contains info on the clicked feature, possibly useful below
    return `<table>
      <tr>
        <td><img class="esri-popup__custom-image imageTrim" width="75" src="http://some.fully.qualified.url/path/image-${randomJSVariable}.png" /></td>
      </tr>             
    </table>`;
},
```

See [the documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-PopupTemplate.html#content) for more information:

> function - Content may be defined with a JavaScript function that returns any of the above-mentioned elements. **This is useful when your popup requires additional processing** or functionality than what is provided with the four content types listed above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works, but only once. If the variable value changes, the popup does not. I'm working on a method to destroy and recreate the popup each time the value is changed. Will post it here as the answer if it works.

Comment: Ah, good point - in that case you want to use a function. I'll update the answer.